# Problems intercepting ManipulationDelta in WP8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, windows-phone-8.1, manipulationdelta

I just got started with an app for WP8.1, and encounter a problem with intercepting touch move events while leaving the original event treatment in place.

What I want to do is the following:

- I have a `ListView` in a `StackPanel` in a `ScrollViewer` in a `Grid`. The ScrollViewer handles vertical scrolling of the StackPanel/ListView.
- Whenever a horizontal touch move appears, I'd like to get a notification so I can adjust some ui element's position based on the horizontal movement.

Sounds simple enough, but any way I tried seems to cancel the original touch move treatment by the `ScrollViewer`, so the vertical scrolling is not working anymore. I'd really hate to implement the whole scrolling behavior myself ...

I tried already:

- Putting a `ManipulationMode="TranslationX" ManipulationDelta="handleXTranslation"` on the `ScrollViewer`. The `handelXTranslation` handler is never called for whatever reason.
- Putting the same Manipulation information on the `ListView` - now the handler gets called (and all handlers of the parent ui elements), but the `ScrollViewer` is not handling the scrolling anymore, probably because the `ListView` is not propagating the event to its parents anymore.
- Adding a general touch handler to the xaml class when it is loaded. Same problem - either it is not called, and if it is called the scrolling of the `ScrollViewer` is not done anymore.

The XAML code looks like this (stripped of some data):

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" ManipulationMode="TranslationX" ManipulationDelta="gridTranslationX">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" ManipulationMode="TranslationX" ManipulationDelta="scrollViewerTranslationX">
        <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" ManipulationMode="TranslationX" ManipulationDelta="scrollViewerTranslationX">
            <ListView x:Name="ListView" ManipulationMode="TranslationX" ManipulationDelta="scrollViewerTranslationX">
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

And the handlers I tried to install in code look like this:

```
this.AddHandler(UIElement.ManipulationDeltaEvent, new ManipulationDeltaEventHandler(genericDeltaHandler), true);
ListView.PointerMoved += new PointerEventHandler(pointerEvent);
```

Is there any way to just *observe* the manipulation events without disturbing their normal treatment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to talk about it ;-) ...

The answer was indeed as simple as adding the **`System`** value to the `ManipulationMode` on the `ListView`:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView" ManipulationMode="TranslateX,System" ManipulationDelta="translationX">
```